# How to open a dialog box after submit a form to show posted successfully - asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a asp.net MVC project. I want to show user a dialog box  after form posted, for user to understand if it was successful or not, and also if user wants to close the dialog box it would be possible.

I searched a lot and read something that I can return partial view but i'm not sure if partial view is what I need in this situation

my question is that is it possible to do it a way with java-script with `.dialog()` or if I should use partial view, then please give me a little explanation how it works.
I need something like this to show after user click on submit button 
http://jsfiddle.net/db5SX/

here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = TempData["ResultMessage"];
        return View();
    }
 public ActionResult Create()
    {


        return View();
    }
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Phone,Message,Date")] Contact_US contact_US)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Contact_US.Add(contact_US);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["ResultMessage"] = "POSTED SUCESSFULLY...!  We WILL CONTACT YOU SOON.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View(contact_US);
    }
```

here is my view if needed:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">


        <h3 class="txtformat padbot50px">Get in touch with us</h3>

        <div class="text-danger message ">
            @ViewBag.ResultMessage
        </div>




        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact_Us", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "contactusform" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">



                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 txtformat" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 txtformat" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 txtformat" })
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group hidden">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 txtformat" })
                    <div class="col-md-12 contactusmsg">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group contactuspostbtn">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input id="postcontactusmessage" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        }





    </div>






</div>
```

information of my layout if needed :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its  bit unclear what you wanting to do - your `Index`view has a form to create a `Contact_US ` object and in the POST method you redirect back to the same view (to display the message/dialog) but why do you want the user to also create another `Contact_US ` object?

Comment: thank u so much. you mean in this line `return View(contact_US)`? because I wanted user to not have to write everything when something happened and fail to save. I create a view for action `create` to return that view when something happens and form didn't save successfully

Comment: No that's not what I meant. Your code is confusing and its unclear what you want to do. In your `Index()` method you have `ViewBag.ResultMessage = TempData["ResultMessage"];` (you redirect to that method from the `Create()` POST method, and in the view you have shown you have `@ViewBag.ResultMessage` which means the view you have shown is `Index.cshtml` - but that makes no sense because that view is also for creating a new `contact_US` object.

Comment: at first it is null so it doesn't show anything to user but when user submit the form and save the form successfully  it redirects to index by this`return RedirectToAction("Index");` while `tempdata` changed to a succeed message. I want to omit this `<div class="text-danger message ">
            @ViewBag.ResultMessage
        </div>` and insted show it in a dialog box  not just a `div` above my form

Comment: Then all you need to do is include the html for the dialog as per your fiddle (and in the `<p>` add `@ViewBag.ResultMessage`. But have the dialog hidden and use javascript to display it if `ViewBag.ResultMessage` is not `null`. But this still does not make sense. Why do you have a `Create.cshtml` view for creating a `contact_US` and an `Index.cshtml` view that also has a form to create a `contact_US`?. And why if it is successful do you want to allow the user to create another `contact_US`?

Comment: Good idea,I worked on something same before but at at first try I left because I thought it may be a wrong attempt.I read something about partial-view and I was confused.__I have Create view for the failure of saving you meant that's better to have just index and return model to fill the inputs while its not save in the index view? and for the last one: do you think that's better to return user to for example home index? then how to show message of succeed to user?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126449/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-neda-derakhshesh).

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to have it abstracted in a base controller and show the message in the `_layouts.cshtml` file, for example:

Create a base controller that will be inherited by all of your controllers

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public string SucccessMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return TempData["SuccessMessage"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = value;
            }
        }

        public string ErrorMessage
        {
            get
            {
                return TempData["ErrorMessage"] as string;
            }
            set
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

In _Layouts.cshtml,

```
 <div class="container body-content" id="bodyContainer">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        @if (@TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
            {
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                @TempData["SuccessMessage"]
            </div>
        }
        else if (@TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                @TempData["ErrorMessage"]
            </div>
        }

        <div class="spacer"></div>
        @RenderBody()
        <hr id="hr" />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Your APp </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Now, all you need to do inside your controller is:

```
public class MyController:BaseController
{
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Email,Phone,Message,Date")] Contact_US contact_US)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Contact_US.Add(contact_US);
            db.SaveChanges();
            SucccessMessage = "POSTED SUCESSFULLY...!  We WILL CONTACT YOU SOON.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


        return View(contact_US);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks good idea. i will work on it but the main problem is that whats the difference between using partial view and opening the dialog box. but you helped such a nice way. I will work on it and will let you know.thanks again

Comment: In the _Layout.cshtml, you can add whatever code you needed, ex: you can add a JavaScript to open a modal dialog or alert or whatever